# Select pytorch tensor elements by list of indices

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I guess I have a pretty simple problem. Let's take the following tensor of length `6`

```
t = torch.tensor([10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60.])
```

Now I would like to to access only the elements at specific indices, lets say at `[0, 3, 4]`. So I would like to return

```
# exptected output 
tensor([10., 40., 50.])
```

I found [torch.index_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html) which worked great for a tensor of two dimensions, e.g. dimension `(2, 4)`, but not for the given `t` for example.

How can access a set of elements based on a given list of indices in a 1-d tensor without using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in fact use `index_select` for this:

```
t = torch.tensor([10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60.])
output = torch.index_select(t, 0, torch.LongTensor([0, 3, 4]))
# output: tensor([10., 40., 50.])
```

You just need to specify the dimension (0) as the second parameter. This is the only valid dimension to specify for a 1-d input tensor.

Answer (score 2):

`index_select` is a reasonable choice, but it will return a **copy** of the selected entries. If you just wanna do some **slicing** on the original tensor, you might use this to access the target items:

```
t = torch.tensor([10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60.])
output = t[(0,3,4),]
# output: tensor([10., 40., 50.])
```

If you have a two-dimension tensor:

```
t = torch.rand(7,2)
output = t[(0,3,4),:]
```

Three-dimension tensor:

```
t = torch.rand(7,2,2)
output = t[(0,3,4),:,:]
```